# what "of the Dunedain" modifying in the sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

> In the westlands of Eriador, between the Misty Mountains and the Mountains of Lune, the Hobbits found both Men and Elves. Indeed, a remnant still dwelt there ***of the Dunedain***, the kings of Men that came over the Sea out of Westernesse; but they were dwindling fast and the lands of their North Kingdom were falling far and wide into waste.

I'm not sure what "of the Dunedain" modifies. It seems to me that it modifies 'remnant'.  If so, why is it put at the end, not close to the word? What does the author try to convey?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The sentence is read:

> Indeed, *a remnant of the Dunedain* still dwelt there

*i.e.* the last survivors of the Dunedain people.

Tolkien likely broke the phrase up for poetic or dramatic effect, or to emphasize the connection to the previous sentence (by keeping the pronoun "there" closer to its antecedent "the westlands of Eriador"). It is certainly not how most people would write or speak today.